# Do Shell Script in Apple Script Results in File not Found

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, applescript

I am trying to make an Apple Script fire off a shell script:

```
do shell script "bash /Users/andrew/script.sh"
```

but I get an error: "bash: /Users/andrew/script.sh: No such file or directory"

I have tried a number of trouble shooting steps including confirming The script runs when I drag the file into terminal and click enter. And to remove any shell script issues I have commented all lines in the shell script.

In Script Editor:

```
read "/Users/andrew/script.sh"
```

Correctly reads the contents of the shell script as text in the result window. This seems like a permissions thing but have no idea what to manipulate to fix it. I even tried the script on different profiles. Any help would be appreciated

the shell script is (as stated comments are purposeful, it does work from within terminal):

```
#!/bin/bash

#diskutil umount /Volumes/Andrew’s\ MacBook\ Pro\ Time\ Machine 

#sudo tmutil addexclusion -v /Volumes/iTunes\ Library

#sudo tmutil addexclusion /Users/Valerie

#sudo tmutil addexclusion /Users/Theodore

#sudo tmutil addexclusion /Users/ReaganBlomquist

#diskutil mount /Volumes/MacBook\ Time\ Machine 

#tmutil startbackup
```

Post script based on comments: the 'bash' in

```
do shell script "bash /users/...
```

is there because the script is a bash script and the default shell in macOS is zsh. I am pretty sure that the script is agnostic to the shell type but as my shebang is for bash I am being internally consistent.

Comment: Your filesystem looks like it's case-sensitive, so `/Users/Andrew` should be `/Users/andrew`

Comment: Can you try `do shell script "/Users/andrew/script.sh"` ?

Comment: Yes, I did try that without the bash prefix. I understand it is necessary, the default shell in macOS is zsh and my shebang is for bash and the bash prefix tells the shell command which shell to use if not the default.

Comment: Ah! Thank you Philip. Turns out my own brevity was hiding the error from you. the path name has spaces in it and when (I Think) Apple Script passed the input of `do shell script` the quotations are not sent over to terminal resulting in the wrong file path. I will post a more detailed answer

Comment: @Andrew The bash prefix is not necessary, and is generally a bad idea (as long as the script has a proper shebang line and execute permission set). zsh is the default *interactive* shell (for newly created accounts) in recent versions of macOS, but this has no effect on how scripts are executed; it *only* affects your interactive shell. If you run a script directly (i.e. not with a command like `bash`, `sh`, `zsh`, `source`, etc), the shebang controls what shell it's run with.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was having too much brevity in my original post. I wanted to be more accurate in my post than `path/to/script.sh` thinking that the problem may be due to MacOS sandboxing and the actual location of the script mattered.

But the actual script path has spaces in it:
`do shell script "bash /Users/Andrew/Do Not Backup iTunes Library.sh"`

I think the way the command works is it passes everything IN the quotations to Terminal but doesn't include the quotes. The way it is written I would need to denote that the block in the quotations was a path name. The command is actually powerful enough that you can write terminal commands directly.

This was revealed to me by Philip in the comments who requested I enter `do shell script "ls -l /Users/andrew/Do Not Backup iTunes Library.sh"` which revealed the additional commands `not` `backup` `iTunes` and `Library` were not valid commands.

Thank you to all who commented and Phillipe, hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Comment: Having spaces in filenames always begs for trouble, but if you do have them, at least use quotes so that the shell knows which parts belong together, i.e. `do shell script "bash /Users/Andrew/'Do Not Backup iTunes Library'.sh`.